# mapController has already been initialized

Tags: flutter

I get 2 pages. On the first one, I choose a location and show my map on page 2.
The first time it works, but when I come back and choose another location, I give this error :
The following LateError was thrown building _BodyBuilder:
LateInitializationError: Field '_state@251051772' has already been initialized.

I use flutter_map and the problem seems to come from my mapController.
I use a provider on page.
Here is the code of page 2.
Thanks for your help.

```
class CarteCo extends StatelessWidget
{
  Map<int, LatLng> mapGpsBalises;
  List <Photo> listPhotos;
  bool balisesVisibles;

  CarteCo({required this.mapGpsBalises, required this.listPhotos, required this.balisesVisibles});


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    //met à jour le provider avec les photos à utiliser et les coordoonées des balises
    Provider.of<LocationProvider>(context, listen: false).init(mapGPSBalises: mapGpsBalises, listePhotos: listPhotos, balVisibles: balisesVisibles);

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Consumer<LocationProvider>
            (builder: (BuildContext context,LocationProvider provider,Widget? child)
          =>Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              if (provider.isTracking==true && provider.noBaliseActuelle<provider.mapGpsBalises.length)...{Text ("balise ${provider.noBaliseActuelle} : "),
                Text ("${provider.distanceBaliseActuelle.toStringAsFixed(3)} kms "),
                Text("${provider.azimutBaliseActuelle.toStringAsFixed(0)} °"),
                IconButton (
                    icon: Icon(Icons.not_interested_sharp),
                    onPressed: ()  async {
                      final ConfirmAction? action = await asyncConfirmDialog(context, "Abandon", "Confirmez vous vouloir abandonner cette balise ?");
                      if (action==ConfirmAction.OUI){
                        //passe à la  balise suivante
                        provider.baliseActuelleSuivante();
                      }
                      provider.rafraichir();
                    }
                ),
              },

              //si on a finit la dernère balise, affiche arrivée
              if (provider.isTracking==true && provider.noBaliseActuelle==provider.mapGpsBalises.length)...{Text ("Arrivée : "),
                Text ("${provider.distanceBaliseActuelle.toStringAsFixed(3)} kms"),
              },

              if ( provider.noBaliseActuelle>provider.mapGpsBalises.length)...{Text ("Allez à l'arrivée et cliquez sur le drapeau"),}
            ],
          ),),
        ),
        body:
        Consumer<LocationProvider>
          (builder: (BuildContext context,LocationProvider provider,Widget? child){
          //appelle la procédure de création des markers
          List<Marker> marker = creationMarkers(provider, context);
          return FlutterMap
            (
            mapController: provider.mapController,
            options: MapOptions
              (
              center: provider.latLng,
              zoom: provider.zoomLevel,
              //intercepte le ontap sur le maps
            ),
            layers: [
              new TileLayerOptions(
                urlTemplate: "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
                subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c'],

              ),
              //le widget  PolylineLayerOptions sert à tracer des polygones sur la carte
              PolylineLayerOptions
                (
                  polylines:
                  [
                    Polyline
                      (
                      //la propriété points contient la liste de points GPS qui vont servir à tracer le polygone
                        points: provider.positions,
                        //propriété qui définit l'épaisseur du trait
                        strokeWidth: 2.0,
                        //couleur de la ligne tracée pour le polygone
                        color: Colors.purple
                    ),
                  ]),

              MarkerLayerOptions
                (
                markers:marker,


              ),
            ],
          );},
        ),

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
fm.FlutterMap(
   options: fm.MapOptions(
      controller: _mapController,
      bounds: bounds,
      center: bounds.center,
      boundsOptions: fm.FitBoundsOptions(
         padding: EdgeInsets.all(30)),
         rotationWinGestures:fm.MultiFingerGesture.pinchZoom),
(...)
```